# Generating server and client certificates with multiple hostnames

Tags: certificates, puppet

When starting up my Puppet Master for the first time, it automatically generates its own server certificate, which is awesome.

My server's hostname is `kungfumaster` and the Puppet Master generates a certificate with the common name being:

```
kungfumaster.mynetwork.com
```

It also adds the following as subject alternative DNS names:

```
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
    DNS:kungfumaster.mynetwork.com, DNS:puppet, DNS:puppet.mynetwork.com
```

I don't exactly know how it found out that this domain lives in `mynetwork.com`, though it does, as `hostname` doesn't reveal the FQDN with any parameter configuration.

However, the one name it seems to have missed is the unqualified host name `kungfumaster`. Interestingly enough, it did append a domain for `puppet` and `puppet.mynetwork.com`, but it conveniently skipped `kungfumaster`.

In my startup script for Puppet Master, how do I generate the server's certificate properly, ie: with all of the required DNS names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before running anything, use the `puppet cert` tool to generate certificate names with a specified list of alternate DNS names:

```
puppet cert generate --dns_alt_names \
    kungfumaster,kungfumaster.mynetwork.com kungfumaster
```

If you've already generated one, clean it out:

```
puppet cert clean -a
```

I still need to figure out how it knows my zone info, but that's another question.