# Determine FQDN when hostname doesn't give it?

Tags: hostname, puppet

In [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/138156/5614), I found that Puppet was generating certificates for my machine's FQDN but not the simple host name. In that example, `kungfumaster` was the hostname and was the value retrieved by running `hostname`. Puppet was generating certificates which specified the FQDN `kungfumaster.domain.com`.

How did Puppet determine that this was my FQDN? I have tried all of the following and not seen anything matching `*.domain.com`:

```
$ hostname -a && hostname -d && hostname --domain && hostname -f && \ 
    hostname --fqdn && hostname -A && hostname --long

kungfumaster
kungfumaster
kungfumaster 
kungfumaster
```

How can I get `kungfumaster.domain.com` from Bash? I've noticed that   `domain.com` does in fact exist in `/etc/resolv.conf`, but I haven't been able to find it anywhere else.

I basically want to get the FQDN of the current machine as a string. The other solutions here on unix.se haven't worked for me. (ie: `dnsdomainname`, `domainname`, etc.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that under-the-hood, Puppet uses Facter to evaluate the domain names:

```
$ facter domain
domain.com
$ facter hostname
kungfumaster
$ facter fqdn
kungfumaster.domain.com
```

The answer is in [the relevant Facter source code](https://github.com/Jimdo/facter/blob/master/lib/facter/domain.rb#L21).

It does the following in order and uses the first one that appears to contain a domain name:

1. hostname -f
2. dnsdomainname
3. parsing resolv.conf for a "domain" or "search" entry

Comment: Ah heck! that link to the Facter source code is no long valid.

Answer (score 3):

Probably because your system is part of a domain network that assigns a domain name. For example in my case, my router resolves all hostnames in the form of `host.lan`, "lan" being my domain, and "host" the name of my system.

The FQDN most likely comes from your router DNS, just run whatever you like of these commands:

```
nslookup your-ip-here
dig -x your-ip-here
host your-ip-here
```

An example using `dig`:

```
dig @10.0.0.1 -x 10.0.0.1

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-4-Debian <<>> @10.0.0.1 -x 10.0.0.1
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 11384
;; flags: qr aa rd ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;1.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa.     IN  PTR

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
1.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa.  86400   IN  PTR dsldevice.lan.

;; Query time: 2181 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.0.1#53(10.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Jun 19 20:01:32 AST 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 77
```

Since I use my own DNS and not the router's I have to set the domain to query in the `@` part. I'm querying the routers' own domain name.

You will find that it will return the domain name as your DNS/router sees you. There are various ways to disable this in the router, but I've found that the most easier way is just using other DNS.

Comment: It actually doesn't do a DNS lookup at all, so this answer is wrong. See Naftuli Tzvi Kay's answer with my edit.

Comment: Actually, it looks like `dnsdomainname` can do a lookup if your own host is not in `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: @jordanm so, it's not wrong?

Comment: Well, in OP's particular context it is, but it could be correct for some users. The OP said `dnsdomainname` did not return the domain name which is the only link in the chain that could do the dns lookup.